# RoR 4 and jQuery - Data Not Updating in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 environment, trying to get some progress bar status to update with current table data on an interval of 1/10 sec.

Here's the code for the setInterval call:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var current_roll = parseInt('<%= @run.current_roll %>', 10);
    var roll_per = (current_roll / max_roll) * 100
    $('#roll_progress_label').html(current_roll);
    $('#roll').attr('aria-valuenow', current_roll);
    $('#roll').attr('style', 'width:' + roll_per + '%');
    // if (current_roll = max_roll) {
    //    clearInterval(roll_interval);
    //  }
  }, 100);
```

I've commented out the clearInterval for testing purposes.

All that math works correctly. The progressbar updates with proper labels and widths, but just once. The interval is not rotating through that code ever 100 milliseconds. It grabs the first value then never changes beyond that. In theory, this code should update the .html of #roll_progress_label on that schedule. (I have also tested this with .text of that div, with no success.)

Also, please note that I have confirmed in the database that all the data is being written correctly.

I know I'm missing something simple. Help!

Comment: I suggest you make it reproducible. You're question does not have an easily reproducible programming problem. You might consider to provide a minimal HTML and suggest some dummy values. `@run.current_roll` is read each interval but how often is its value updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet if you added a `console.log` you'd see that this function does run every 100 milliseconds. The server renders `@run.current_roll` exactly one time so the value of `current_roll` is always going to be the same.

I think what you want is either polling (make a request to the server every X milliseconds) or something like [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) (which I hear is easier in Rails 5 but I don't have any direct experience with WebSockets on Rails).

Comment: Hi Andy,

Thanks for your comment. I have confirmed through other means that it is firing, but also see what you mean by the polling with something like WebSockets. I'm looking into that now, and will post a solution when I code it.

Comment: Marking as answer because it got me on the right track. Long polling with WebSockets got me on the path of Pusher and SSE. Pusher actually got me data I needed on a stream that was easy to update the DOM, but I am in no position to pay a third party. I am continuing down research of coding in house. Thanks, @Andy.